# WebStorm Vue directives in HTML highlighting

Tags: html, syntax, vue.js, webstorm, syntax-highlighting

Is there are way to change highlight the vue attributes and directives? Also in quotes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no special color scheme for Vue.js.
But it looks as if Vue.js support is not enabled for your template anyway - `@click` is highlighted as syntax error, values appear as simple string literals. Normally this code is highlighted as follows:

[image]

i.e. attribute names are shown according to **Attribute name** preferences (**Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | HTML**), and values - according to JavaScript preferences for instance member functions/variables (**Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | JavaScript**)

**Hint**: you can assign preferred shortcut to **Settings | Keymap | Other | Jump to Colors and Fonts** and use it to navigate to color settings of element under cursor